# Hook into django field assignment

Tags: python, django, orm, django-forms

When creating a "vanilla" python class, if one wants to execute code on assignment to an attribute, the usual pattern to to create a "protected" (leading-underscore) attribute to hold the data, and use `property` to create getters and setters.

Now, if I wanted to do that with a Django model, that would be unattractive, not least because I would have to search on the underscore-version of the property.

**What is the recommended way to run code on field-assignment in Django?**

There is no signal that I can find to do this; the only other approach I can see would be to use a custom Field that can register additional getter/setter handlers.

Answer (score 1):

You simply can't do that on a non-custom field, because there is no actual "field": it's a simple attribute, with no class behind it.

You'll need to define a custom field class and override `to_python` - don't forget to set the metaclass to [`SubfieldBase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-model-fields/#the-subfieldbase-metaclass).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like dirtyfields is what you want. You can't intercept at exactly the same time the value is set, but you can hook in before saving. http://code.activestate.com/pypm/django-dirtyfields/

Alternatively, you should set up `@properties` with set methods. Of course this would require you to duplicate your actual `django.db.models.fields` fields with getters and setters.